# Quadrilateral to rectangle transform

Tags: matlab, transformation

I want to transform a quadrilateral image to a rectangular image which I know those vertices. for example in the image below, I know the coordinate (X1,Y1) ~ (X4,Y4) and (x1,y1) ~ (x2,y2) and I want to transform it into rectangle. how can I obtain (x,y) coordinate in rectangular image which is correspond to (X,Y) coordinate in quadrilateral image?

```
 ____> Y             ____> y            
|                   |                               
|                   |    
V                   V
X                   x               

(X1,Y1)   (X2,Y2)        (x1,y1)    (x1,y2)
    ________                 _________
   / .(X,Y) \   =>          |  .(x,y) |
  /__________\              |_________|
(X3,Y3)    (X4,Y4)       (x2,y1)    (x2,y2)
```

Comment: Check this link, it has the exact solve: http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~cwren/interpolator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is supposed to be a perspective transformation, the term you look for is [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography).
Maybe the Matlab functions in these links cando what you want:

http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/#projective

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/

Edited after comments:
Ok, so I solved the equations with Mathematica. If you define (for readability)

```
M=(x-x1)/(x2-x1)
```

and

```
N=(y-y1)/(y2-y1),
```

then the pair of solutions is the rather unwieldy

```
{M -> -(X1 Y - X3 Y + X4 Y - X Y1 - X4 Y1 + X Y2 - 2 X1 Y2 + X3 Y2 + 
   X Y3 - X2 (Y - 2 Y1 + Y3) - X Y4 + 
   X1 Y4 + \[Sqrt](4 (X3 (-Y + Y1) + X1 (Y - Y3) + 
         X (-Y1 + Y3)) (-(X3 - X4) (Y1 - Y2) + (X1 - X2) (Y3 - 
            Y4)) + (X4 (-Y + Y1) + X3 (Y - 2 Y1 + Y2) + 
        X2 (Y - Y3) - X1 (Y - 2 Y3 + Y4) + 
        X (Y1 - Y2 - Y3 + Y4))^2))/(2 (-(X2 - X4) (Y1 - 
        Y3) + (X1 - X3) (Y2 - Y4))), 
N -> -(-X2 Y - X3 Y + X4 Y - X Y1 + 2 X3 Y1 - X4 Y1 + X Y2 - X3 Y2 +
    X Y3 + X2 Y3 - X Y4 + 
   X1 (Y - 2 Y3 + 
      Y4) - \[Sqrt](4 (X3 (-Y + Y1) + X1 (Y - Y3) + 
         X (-Y1 + Y3)) (-(X3 - X4) (Y1 - Y2) + (X1 - X2) (Y3 - 
            Y4)) + (X4 (-Y + Y1) + X3 (Y - 2 Y1 + Y2) + 
        X2 (Y - Y3) - X1 (Y - 2 Y3 + Y4) + 
        X (Y1 - Y2 - Y3 + Y4))^2))/(2 (-(X3 - X4) (Y1 - 
        Y2) + (X1 - X2) (Y3 - Y4)))}
```

and

```
{M -> -(X1 Y - X3 Y + X4 Y - X Y1 - X4 Y1 + X Y2 - 2 X1 Y2 + X3 Y2 + 
   X Y3 - X2 (Y - 2 Y1 + Y3) - X Y4 + 
   X1 Y4 - \[Sqrt](4 (X3 (-Y + Y1) + X1 (Y - Y3) + 
         X (-Y1 + Y3)) (-(X3 - X4) (Y1 - Y2) + (X1 - X2) (Y3 - 
            Y4)) + (X4 (-Y + Y1) + X3 (Y - 2 Y1 + Y2) + 
        X2 (Y - Y3) - X1 (Y - 2 Y3 + Y4) + 
        X (Y1 - Y2 - Y3 + Y4))^2))/(2 (-(X2 - X4) (Y1 - 
        Y3) + (X1 - X3) (Y2 - Y4))), 
N -> -(-X2 Y - X3 Y + X4 Y - X Y1 + 2 X3 Y1 - X4 Y1 + X Y2 - X3 Y2 +
    X Y3 + X2 Y3 - X Y4 + 
   X1 (Y - 2 Y3 + 
      Y4) + \[Sqrt](4 (X3 (-Y + Y1) + X1 (Y - Y3) + 
         X (-Y1 + Y3)) (-(X3 - X4) (Y1 - Y2) + (X1 - X2) (Y3 - 
            Y4)) + (X4 (-Y + Y1) + X3 (Y - 2 Y1 + Y2) + 
        X2 (Y - Y3) - X1 (Y - 2 Y3 + Y4) + 
        X (Y1 - Y2 - Y3 + Y4))^2))/(2 (-(X3 - X4) (Y1 - 
        Y2) + (X1 - X2) (Y3 - Y4)))}
```

Note that the only difference is the sign before the Srqt.

Now you only have to re-form the definitions of `M` and `N` above to get `x`,`y`. `x=M*(x2-x1)+x1`, `y=N*(y2-y1)+y1`.

Comment: Please review the question again.

Comment: Well, the way I understand your edit, that's two equations (X=..., Y=...) for two unknowns (x,y). That should be half a page of transforming equations. Enter w1-w4 into the equations, isolate x and y, done. No need to bother Matlab before that. Are you able (mathematically) to do that? It's good practice to at least try. If you don't succeed, comment.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you truly or not. do you mean something like that:
    w1=f(X,Y,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4)
    w2 ~ w4 etc...
    x=x1.w1+x2.w2+x3.w3+x4.w4
    y=y1.w1+y2.w2+y3.w3+y4.w4
now, should I calculate f function mathematically?

Comment: if you meant so, I think its really hard to calculate f function.

Comment: I considered your comment precisely. thanks for that. unfortunately I'm not familiar with Mathematica, however, finally whats the solutions for (x,y) ? I'll be glad if you visit this photo:

[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya1s4.png)

Comment: you don't need mathematica, i gave you the solution. Anyway, I edited my answer again.

Comment: I implemented your solution with MATLAB. Thanks for that. it works correctly when I use -sqrt for M relation and +sqrt for N relation. but when I use vice versa, the result is not true. so, when should I use +sqrt for M relation and -sqrt for N relation?

Comment: There has been a question about your answer: [Quadrilateral to rectangle transform (Using solution formulas of Christoph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615005/quadrilateral-to-rectangle-transform-using-solution-formulas-of-christoph)