# Quadrilateral to rectangle transform (Using solution formulas of Christoph)

Tags: delphi, math

I'm trying to solve early discussed problem on Delphi, using Christoph's solution([Quadrilateral to rectangle transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276037/quadrilateral-to-rectangle-transform7)).
Unfortunately, I'm catching a mistake with formulas for M and N ((( As I investigated, a negative value appears in SQRT(...). Christoph, is it all right between the formulas' definitions of X1,Y1.. and task conditions (especially order of quadrilateral points)? What were your definitions? Wouldn't it be too impudent to ask you for an analythic formulas of M and N (I mean picture of equation) - i'm not strong in Mathematica syntax... Thank you!

Comment: You should either ask that as a comment under Christoph's answer to that question; or elaborate on your question and really make it a standalone question. Right now, it looks like only this Christoph can answer, but they won't see your question here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not enough points to leave a comment under Christoph's answers. And yes, I would like to ask Christoph directly, but I didn't find a personal message possibility....

Comment: Thanks for pinging! Sorry, I can't help you here, this was 10 years ago, and I don't have access to Mathematica anymore. :-/

Comment: Thanks for answer! So, you didn't have any files left?

Answer (score 0):

To make "Quadrilateral to rectangle transform", you need to get matrix of perspective transformation. [Theory](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2008_fall/Papers/proj.pdf)

You can apply OpenCV function [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae) to arrays of source quadrilateral vertices and destination rectangle vertices. Then apply perpective transformation to needed points (**perspectiveTransform**) or to the whole image if needed (**warpPerspective**). You mentioned Delphi - Delphi headers [do exist](https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV) for older OpenCV version (2.4.13).

Also you can extract perspective tranformation code from [Pascal version of AGG library](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/) (weird translation from C++)

Comment: Thanks for advise, I solved this task with my own distortion algorithm, without matrix calculations